# Why Access key of azure blockchain service stops working at a fixed time everyday?

Tags: azure, blockchain, azure-blockchain-service

I've deployed smartcontract using the same access key and also wrote and read the data through API. But suddenly I'm unable to connect. The connection isn't continuous.
I'm unable to connect from metamask as well, when it stops working for my APIs.

This happens often. I'm not able to connect with azure blockchain using the Access Key for a certain period of time nearly hours and after that without any change if I retry it connects.

Everyday it stops working after 13:30 IST.

What could be the issue ?

Please guide me.
Thank you!

Comment: I see the same issue posted on Q&A : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/50206/index.html